# parse an array of string to a matrix of Int

Tags: arrays, split, julia

I'm using Julia.

When parsing a string to Int,
`parse.(Int,split(readline()))` works
(e.g. input:`""123 456""` → output:`[123,456]`),

but `parse.(Int,split(readlines()))` doesn't. How should I do?

I know each `parse.(Int,split(readlines()[i]))` passes, but I want to parse at one try something like `parse.(Int,split(readlines()))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the nicest way would be by `using DelimitedFiles` such as:

```
julia> open("f.txt", "w") do f; println(f,"1 2 3\n4 5 6"); end

julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> readdlm("f.txt",Int)
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

Something more similar to your code could look like this:

```
julia> map(row -> parse.(Int,row), split.(readlines("f.txt")))
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks! ```map(row -> parse.(Int,row), split.(readlines("f.txt")))``` is what I need.  ```using DelimitedFiles``` takes much time in the Competitive programming.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the `DelimitedFiles` package from the Julia standard library:

```
julia> readdlm(stdin, Int)
1 23 4 
6 83 23
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  23   4
 6  83  23
```

(the second and third lines are user input by me.)

If you're reading from a file (`readline("myfile.txt")` in the original code), you can pass the filename instead of `stdin` (`readdlm("myfile.txt", Int)`).